# why is my japplet displays gray block in browser after adding an image icon?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, japplet, imageicon

My japplet is able to run normally in NetBeans environment, but shows only a gray block screen in my browser (Chrome, IE). But when I removed all the image icons from my japplet, it runs normally in the browser and I have totally no idea why. Need some guidance for this.

My japplet class content

```
public void init() 
{
    try { UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel"); }

    catch(Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex); }       

    try 
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { public void run() { initComponents(); } });
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

    jlbReg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/MyIcons/icon1.png"))); 
    jlbAnn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/MyIcons/icon2.png")));
    jlbSubmit.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/MyIcons/icon3.png")));
    jlbForum.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/MyIcons/icon4.png")));
}
```

My html content

```
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="MyJApplet.class" width=1150  height=1000></APPLET>
```

Comment: Check the Java Console for error messages.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at LearnerMain.initComponents(LearnerMain.java:104)
 at LearnerMain.access$000(LearnerMain.java:6)
 at LearnerMain$1.run(LearnerMain.java:31)

I think this is the main problem, but I don't understand why. My image icons resources worked fine in my IDE.

Comment: Your applet doesn't seem to find the images. Place the images in their relative folder

Comment: I did placed my images in the source folder  
C:\Users\MyName\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\src

Comment: What is the output of `jar -tvf MyJAR.jar`?  Copy/paste it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20315542/edit).  And please refrain from putting code or exception output in comments, where it is virtually unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Your applet can't find the images in the jar file. Wait a minute - that's because you're not using a jar file. You need to use a jar file.

Comment: I have tried this, but still the same 
<APPLET archive="MyJAR.jar" codebase="classes" code="MyJApplet.class" width=1150  height=1000></APPLET>

Comment: My JAR file in the dist folder, executed the html file in the build folder

Comment: Are the images inside the jar file? If so, in which folder?

Comment: Yes the images are in the jar file, I created a folder called MyIcons and placed all the images inside.